# How can I have vim execute a shell command upon every :w?

Tags: vim

Basically, I have a pre-processor for my code which reads all my `.foo` files and converts them to corresponding compiled `.bar` versions, though without ever modifying any of the originals. Each time I write changes to my source files, I would like vim to `!./run-my-preprocessor-script.js` after it has finished saving my file. How can this be done? I only want this to happen when I'm editing files with names ending in `.foo`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Vim’s `autocmd` feature (see `:help :autocmd`). It has lots of hooks for “events”; the one you want should be *BufWritePost*. E.g., in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.foo !./run-my-preprocessor-script.js
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`autocmd`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/12.html) to hook into the `BufWritePost` event like so:

```
autocmd BufWritePost * execute '!ls'
```

This means that every time the `BufWritePost` (after the buffer has been written) event is triggered on any file, you'll execute the command `!ls`. It's easy to specialize this to work only on `*.foo` files that are saved:

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.foo execute '!ls'
```

Now, the command `!ls` will only be triggered when a file with a filename matching the expression `*.foo` is written.

Obviously, you'll need to change `ls` to whatever you do to execute your preprocessor script, but the process is the same. Put that modified `autocmd` into your `.vimrc` file and it should work!